# Why am I dying when I go outside?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I admittedly haven't played *Oblivion* in a while and may have forgotten something as whenever I go outside, my player starts losing health. I know this wasn't happening to my player before stopping playing.

I completed a mission in a dungeon from my last save, head outside, and my health slowly depletes until I'm dead. I can't fast travel anywhere because of it, and healing potions only delay it.

1. What should I look for?
2. Can it be fixed?

If it matters, I'm playing the Xbox 360 version.

Comment: What is this "outside" that you speak of?

Comment: It's the daystar! It burns!

Comment: That's because of no internets!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's most likely that your character is a [vampire](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion%3aVampirism). There's a quest you can complete, [found on the wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Vampire_Cure), that will cure this. [It's also possible to cure it using the console](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion%3aVampirism#Curing_Vampirism). Other than that, you can avoid damage by staying out of the sun, and fast traveling at night.

Comment: +1 That's exactly what's going on. No other explanation.

Comment: Well... damn. I don't recall that happening. Guess I need to find this questline to cure this stuff.

Comment: Can you even access the console on a console? I don't think that's a valid solution :)

Comment: No, we can't, but it wouldn't hurt to have for someone not on a console.

Comment: Or, instead of curing it, you could just feed. IIRC, sun doesn't harm you for the first 24 hours after feeding. Of course, not feeding has its advantages as well...

Answer (score 4):

You have vampirism.

An easy way to get rid of it: Theres a glitch. First go into the water then drown. After you're dead, load your last save and vampirism will vanish, but not permanently. Maybe the next month you'll get vampireism.

Answer (score 0):

The Hands of midnight, that you get from the dark brotherhood, give you sun damage. Pretty stupid and it took me forever to realize I wasn't a vampire